# pouchdb-server - Install without sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite, pouchdb

I am trying to install pouchdb-server as shown below:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential
sudo npm install -g pouchdb-server
```

The installation is stuck in an infinite loop with `sqlite3`. The following message appears repeatedly.

```
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/pouchdb-server/node_modules/sqlite3/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/pouchdb-server/node_modules/sqlite3/.node-gyp/8.11.1"
```

How do I get rid of these messages for a successful installation?

Comment: `... user "root" does not have permission to ...` If *root* doesn't have permission, who else has?

Comment: I am using a Ubuntu-16.04 AWS EC2 `t2.medium` instance. I don't know how else to use super user privileges.

Answer (score 1):

The following rids the errors mentioned above.

`sudo npm install -g pouchdb-server --ignore-scripts`